# How to change the referenced cell number, not letter

Tags: excel, cell

I have a couple of sheets in excel. The first sheet is a table and the second sheet will display one row from the table on a single page. Currently when I want to see a row, I change all the values in sheet 2, for example:

```
=Sheet1!A4
```

I change this manually for all cells A-H, and it takes time... I was hoping I could shorten it by having one value on Sheet2 where I can type a number, and all cells will change to reference that row. The way I thought was something like this:

```
=Sheet1!A(J1)       *where J1 has a value, eg. 4, the formula would read "=Sheet1!A4"
```

Obviously this doesn't work... Is there any way to achieve this? It would be really helpful and save a lot of time

Comment: Consider using `INDIRECT()`

Comment: How exactly would I use this? I briefly looked into it, but didn't think it applied

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
=index(Sheet1!a:a, j1)
```

The [INDIRECT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-21f8bcfc-b174-4a50-9dc6-4dfb5b3361cd) is volatile¹; the [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) is not.

---

¹ <sub>Volatile functions recalculate whenever anything in the entire workbook changes, not just when something that affects their outcome changes. Examples of **volatile** functions are [INDIRECT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-21f8bcfc-b174-4a50-9dc6-4dfb5b3361cd), [OFFSET](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-b3958b36-c30b-4fc3-979e-9b9bbfdcf592), [TODAY](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TODAY-function-62B76639-BA50-4F86-AD4E-1A74FB2EA566), [NOW](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/NOW-function-3337FD29-145A-4347-B2E6-20C904739C46), [RAND](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/RAND-function-4CBFA695-8869-4788-8D90-021EA9F5BE73) and [RANDBETWEEN](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/RANDBETWEEN-function-4CC7F0D1-87DC-4EB7-987F-A469AB381685). Some sub-functions of the [CELL](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CELL-function-51BD39A5-F338-4DBE-A33F-955D67C2B2CF) and [INFO](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INFO-function-725f259a-0e4b-49b3-8b52-58815c69acae) worksheet functions will make them volatile as well.</sub>